# JUnit Mockito test fails with equalTo

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to understand why adding in **equalTo** is making my test fail.
I have recreated the problem with a simple class and test.

The first test passes and the second test fails.

Sample Class

```
public class Class {

Map<String, Boolean> data = new HashMap<>();

public Map<String, Boolean> getData(boolean access) {
    if (!access) 
        return null;
    return data;
}}
```

Test Class

```
public class ClassTest {

@InjectMocks
private Class testObj;

@Test
public void testGetDataNull() {
    assertThat(testObj.getData(false), is(nullValue()));
}

@Test
public void testGetDataNull2() {
    assertThat(testObj.getData(false), is(equalTo(nullValue())));
}}
```

The test that fails is showing this error message

```
Expected: is <null>
  but: was null
```

Q: What is the difference between these?

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: My guess would be that in the second test you are actually checking if the result of _getData(false)_ is equal to the Matcher object produced by _nullValue()_. Try using *null* instead.

Comment: Please do not name your class `Class`. This can cause you all kinds of problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because `nullValue()` returns a `org.hamcrest.core.isNull` object. So it is not equal to `null`, it is an object. However that object contains a `matches` method which will only match `null`, which is why `is` works.

As an aside, the test should probably just read `assertNull(testObj.getData(false))`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is actually about Hamcrest, not Mockito.

you're testing if the actual value, i.e. `testObj.getData(false)`, which is `null`, is equal to the value returned by `nullValue()`, which is an instance of the IsNull() matcher. An instance of IsNull is not equal to `null`, hence the failure.

I'd recommend avoiding Hamcrest, which in my opinion is harder to use correctly and less elegant than [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/index.html).

With AssertJ, you would write

```
assertThat(testObj.getData(false)).isNull();
```

No static method to guess anymore, and valid autocompleted fluent assertions instead.